# Check if string contains only floats separated with commas in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

How can I check if string contains only floats separated by commas with no space. 
Something like below:

```
str = "0.0687987167581341,0.120311605902415,89.8399554017928,198.151088713489"  #true
str = "0.068798716758f1341,0.120311605902415, 89.8399554017928,198.151088713489" #False because of "f" in the first value.
str = "0.0687987167581341 0.120311605902415" # False because of no space and comma.
```

Basically, how can I check if a string is in the form below:

```
str = "<value>,<value>,<value>" # where value may only contains, integers, floats.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following matches, then it means that `str` does not satisfy the condition.

```
str =~ /[^\d.,]/
```

So, taking the negation:

```
re = /[^\d.,]/
"0.0687987167581341,0.120311605902415,89.8399554017928,198.151088713489" !~ re
# => true
"0.068798716758f1341,0.120311605902415, 89.8399554017928,198.151088713489" !~ re
# => false
"0.0687987167581341 0.120311605902415" !~ re
# => false
```

Comment: This reports valid for a string like `str = ".,.,4.,"`. I don't think that's right.

Comment: @Linuxios It depends on what OP means by a float, and how much variety is to be expected in the input.

Comment: You have a point. I still doubt that `.` or `4.` are valid inputs.

Answer (score 2):

How about this regexp:

```
str.split(',').all? {|val| val =~ /\A-?\d+(\.\d+)?\Z/}
```

Comment: Thanks this works but not when there's only an integer.

Comment: user3187131, please give an example where it does not work.  Linuxios, perhaps allow for negative numbers.

Comment: user3187131, please either remove your assertion that this solution doesn't work "when there's only an integer", or provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I thought the title of the question was pretty clear, but obviously not, as I now see that the string may also contain integers.  Whether negative numbers are permitted is left unsaid, but `-2.1` is a float and `-3` is an integer.  In any event, my solution works only for floats, though it would not be difficult to modify it to permit integers as well, but that would be too messy to bother with.

I prefer @Linuxios' solution, but I'll mention another approach in the interest of diversity.  If we are not concerned about the possibility of extra leading or trailing zeroes, this should work:

```
str = "0.0687987167581341,0.120311605902415,89.8399554017928,198.151088713489"

str.split(',').all? { |s| s.to_f.to_s == s.strip }
  #=>true
```

If there be extra leading or trailing zeros, or extra whitespace, I believe this would work:

```
str.split(',').all? {|s| s.to_f.to_s == 
  s.match(/^\s*(-)?\s*?0*?(0.\d+?|[1-9]\d*\.\d+?)0*\s*$/)[1..-1].join
```