# What does the !~ method do with String in Ruby

Tags: ruby

From @sawa's answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21892359/226255

What does `!~` do?

Example:

```
re = /[^\d.,]/
"0.0687987167581341,0.120311605902415,89.8399554017928,198.151088713489" !~ re
```

I couldn't find any documentation in [String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html) or [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `!~` is the inverse of `=~`, that is `!(=~)`. From the [Ruby `Object#!~` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-21-7E):

> [obj !~ other ] returns true if two objects do not match (using the =~ method), otherwise false.

So, since [`String#=~`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) performs a string/regex match returning the index of the first match if matched and `nil` otherwise, `String#!~` return `false` if matched and `true` otherwise.

Comment: Technically `=~` returns an index into the string pointing to the first occurrence of the pattern which, being a `Fixnum` is truthy and returns `nil` otherwise (which is of course falsey).

Comment: @olleicua: ok, thanks olleicua's pry :D Abdo: lately Ruby documentation got much better, you can find almost everything there; instead, 1.8.7 was much more obscure...

Answer (score 1):

It means the regex does *not* match. It's the inverse of `=~`

Also mentioned here: [Does Ruby regular expression have a not match operator like "!~" in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759091/does-ruby-regular-expression-have-a-not-match-operator-like-in-perl)

Apparently it's not documented for some reason.

Comment: It's not apparent, you're just not looking in the right place.

Comment: @theTinMan - so that merits downvoting a correct answer? If you had actually looked at the link I included you'd see that other people made the reasonable assumption that such a function would be documented in string or regex.